# Лемма о накачке (Pumping lemma)

Tags: теория-автоматов

Так как вопрос более относится к программированию нежели к математике я бы очень хотел задать его здесь. Но местное форматирование не поддерживает использование формул как на форуме математики. Поэтому прошу прощения, что я позволил себе оттуда утянуть вопрос скриншотом сюда ([Лемма о разрастании](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B5)):

[image]

Comment: С помощью этой леммы, как мне кажется, можно доказать, что язык из одного однобуквенного слова L = {a} не является регулярным: пусть x = e, y = a, z = e, тогда все слова a* принадлежат языку L. Но a^2 не принадлежит языку L. Следовательно, язык L не является регулярным. Где ошибка?

Comment: @Flammable: лемма утверждает, что "накачать" можно достаточно длинные строки (начиная с некоторой длины). Для конечного языка лемма тривиально выполняется -- возьмём начальную длину больше макс. длины слова в языке, все такие слова (а их пустое множество) можно накачать.

Comment: @Dex: мы не можем так просто положить n = 4. Лемма утверждает лишь "найдётся n, начиная с которого...".

Comment: @VladD, спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Для начала, язык `A` регулярен (например, он описывается регулярным выражением `(ww)*`).

Лемма о накачке не может быть использована для доказательства регулярности языка, ведь она сформулирована для регулярных языков, и значит, *выводит* свойства из факта регулярности. Если язык обладает свойством накачки (описанным в лемме), он может быть и регулярным, и нерегулярным: лемма не запрещает нерегулярным языкам обладать этим свойством.

При помощи леммы можно, однако, доказать *нерегулярность* языка: если условие накачки не выполняется, язык точно не регулярный, от противного.

Приведённые вами соображения не доказывают нерегулярность, так как они не доказывают невыполнение условия накачки. Условие накачки утверждает лишь, что для достаточно длинных слов *возможно* накачиваемое разбиение, оно вовсе не требует, чтобы *любое* разбиение было накачиваемым. То, что вы привели ненакачиваемое разбиение, не означает, что ненакачиваемого разбиения не существует.

Если вы захотите доказать нерегулярность, вам придётся показать, что для любой наперёд заданной длины найдётся слово, *никакое* разбиение которого не накачиваемо. (Но в нашем случае это не удастся, потому что язык всё же регулярный.)

И да, вопрос скорее по математике, чем по программированию.

Comment: Задача из книги, в которой весьма однозначно сказано, что A = {w|w^n, n - четные} - нерегулярен. И дело в том, что ваш второй абзац звучит разумно, но что считать правильным в каком-то конкретном случае - для меня загадка.

Comment: @Dex: Хм. Вот [этот ответ](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/1707) согласен с моим мнением о регулярности языка, и приводит в общем те же аргументы. (И кажется упоминает то же упражнение.)

Answer (score 0):

Первое разбиение не подходит, потому что при четных i xy^iz не пренадлежит A. Второе разбиение подходит под условия леммы, значит A регулярно.

Comment: @gkuznets, мы же не разбиения проверяем. То, что вы написали я и так знаю, но где написано, что "для всех разбиений" или "хотя бы для одного разбиения"?

Comment: Да, написал ерунду. Лемма говорит о том, что если язык регулярный, то для некоторого n, для всех слов длины не менее n существует разбиение ...

В обратную сторону лемма не работает.

Так что мне не очень понятно, какое отношение имеет pumping lemma к решению вопроса о регулярности A.

Comment: А при чем здесь, простите, "обратная сторона"?

Comment: Я в своем исходном ответе попытался применить лемму в обратную сторону.

Comment: Ясно, странно, но ладно